# Need to remove 'Featured', 'Date' and 'Comments' from WordPress Sticky Post?

Tags: php

I need to remove the 'Featured', 'Date' and 'Comments' from my Twenty Eleven child theme sticky post that I have on my landing page.

I am finding it hard to find any information that show what functions I will need to override and what files they reside in. Does anyone know what I need to override and help point me in the right direction.

I have amended the 'loop' in index.php adding  which only shows the posts that are not sticky. I now need to remove the comments etc from sticky post, any idea as to what function(s) I will need to override? Thanks in advance

code for index.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if( !is_sticky() || !is_home() ) :?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>` is calling the content template, you'll need to edit that template view and remove the things you don't want. Or wrap them in if statements of some sort.

Comment: most likely, if its the featured content you want to edit. if its regular content, its probably content.php

Comment: Ahh I see do you think it will be a if(!is_sticky()) display as normal else {nothing for comments etc}, in content.php Thanks for your input Magimarkker am I on the right lines??

Comment: Yep sounds about right to me!

Comment: Gonna giv it a go,

Comment: removed the line <h3 class="entry-format"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3> from content.php which has removed featured! great so far, thanks!

Comment: added !is_sticky() to the below condition in content.php which has removed comments, Thanks! <?php if ( comments_open() && ! post_password_required() && !is_sticky()) : ?>